# Looping on number value TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to loop on this variable that I have created before :

`{% set divisionElement = (elementsLength/2)|round|number_format(0) %}`

The output of this is a number.

After that I would like to create a loop with this value like that :

```
{% for i in divisionElement %}
 {{dump(i}}
{% endfor %}
```

When I tried to dump `i` in my loop I have nothing result.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [range](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/range.html), If `divisionElement` is > 0

```
{% for i in range(1, divisionElement ) %}
    {{ i }},
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot ! output of divisionElement is a string, we can convert this on number element. Thank enjoy

Comment: I guess you have number by applying [`number_format`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) ?